# Synonyms in Solr Query Results

Tags: solr, synonym, querying

Whenever I query a string in solr, i want to get the synonyms of field value if there exists any as a part of query result, is it possible to do that in solr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to fetch the synonyms used in the search results. You can get close by looking at how Solr parsed your query via the `debugQuery=true` parameter and looking at the `parsedQuery` value in the response but it would not be straightforward. For example, if you search for "tv" on a text field that uses synonyms you will get something like this:

```
$ curl "localhost:8983/solr/your-core/select?q=tv&debugQuery=true"
{
...
    "parsedquery":"SynonymQuery(Synonym(_text_:television _text_:televisions _text_:tv _text_:tvs))",
...
```

Another approach would be to load in your application the `synonyms.txt` file that Solr uses and do the mapping yourself. Again, not straightforward,

Comment: thank you, it does solve my issue partially, let's say i search for "tv", and the result query has another field, where the field value has synonym, can that synonym be fetched, for ex a smart tv has 5 gb of internal storage, i query for "Tv", can i get the synonyms of "gb" as well

Comment: You are correct, there is no easy way of knowing which of the synonyms was a match. The information in parsedQuery will tell you which synonyms it processed but not which ones actually matched.